# SQLAlchemy: IntegrityError on cascade delete for children with siblings

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I have the following ORM (shortend excerpt):

```
class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class Resource:
    resource_id: Mapped[UUID] = mapped_column(
        Uuid,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        primary_key=True,
        index=True,
    )
    created: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(DateTime, server_default=func.now())
    updated: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(DateTime, server_default=func.now())

class Chat(Base, Resource):
    __tablename__ = "chats"

    messages = relationship(
        "Message",
        back_populates="chat",
        cascade="all, delete",
        order_by="Message.created",
    )

class Message(Base, Resource):
    __tablename__ = "messages"

    previous_message_id: Mapped[UUID] = mapped_column(
        Uuid, ForeignKey("messages.resource_id"), nullable=True
    )
    chat_id: Mapped[UUID] = mapped_column(Uuid, ForeignKey("chats.resource_id"))
    chat = relationship("Chat", back_populates="messages")
```

When I try to delete a Chat from the database (Postgres), I get the following IntegrityError

> sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.ForeignKeyViolation) update or delete on table "messages" violates foreign key constraint "messages_previous_message_id_fkey" on table "messages"
>
> DETAIL:  Key (resource_id)=(4d57d1eb-eb07-4983-a320-863f5529b1e5) is still referenced from table "messages".

I get that there is a circular dependency and that it tries to delete a message that is references by another one, but I was wondering if I can force it to delete the messages in a  specific order since there is a tree of messages and deleting them in order of creation from newest to oldest wouldn't violate any constraints.

Or is it possible to somehow instruct it to ignore the constraint? I'm not sure if `delete-orphan` is helpful here or even how to apply it. I don't want to remove the foreign key constraint on `previous_chat_message` because I like the validation that comes with it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `on_delete` strategies for your foring keys

for example look at on delete cascade explanation here
https://medium.com/the-table-sql-and-devtalk/postgres-on-delete-cascade-a-comprehensive-guide-a186ac558a8b

And for other options
https://medium.com/@dilongfa/understand-about-on-update-and-on-delete-5d465c538501